# Buffer size is not sufficient or queue is full when making many Http Requests

Tags: c#, concurrency, wikipedia-api

I am currently trying to get a lot of data about video games out of Wikipedia using their public API. I've gotten some of the way. I can currently get all the `pageid` I need with their associated article `title`. But then I need to get their Unique Identifiers (Qxxxx where x are numbers) and that takes quite a while...possibly because I have to make single queries for every title (there are 22031) or because I don't understand Wikipedia Queries.

So I thought "Why not just make multiple queries at once?" so I started working on that, but I've run into the issue in the title. After the program has run for a while (usually 3-4 minutes) about a minute passes then the application crashes with the error in the title. I think it's because my approach is just bad:

```
ConcurrentBag<Entry> entrybag = new ConcurrentBag<Entry>(entries);
Console.WriteLine("Getting Wikibase Item Ids...");
Parallel.ForEach<Entry>(entrybag, (entry) =>
{
    entry.WikibaseItemId = GetWikibaseItemId(entry).Result;
});
```

Here is the method that is called:

```
async static Task<String> GetWikibaseItemId(Entry entry)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php");
        entry.Title.Replace("+", "Plus");
        entry.Title.Replace("&", "and");
        String queryString = "?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&format=json&redirects=1&titles=" + entry.Title;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        String result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
        String data = deserialized.ToString();
        try
        {
            if (data.Contains("wikibase_item"))
            {
                return deserialized["query"]["pages"]["" + entry.PageId + ""]["pageprops"]["wikibase_item"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "NONE";
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException)
        {
            return "NULL";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
}
```

And just for good measure, here is the Entry Class:

```
public class Entry
{
    public EntryCategory Category { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String WikibaseItemId { get; set; }
}
```

Could anyone perhaps help out? Do I just need to change how I query or something else?

Comment: limit the number of concurrently running queries to a reasonable number, like 10, instead of 22k

Comment: The crash is because the server didn't like the query.  Try the query manually by putting it into the URL of the webpage.  You application is just timing out after 3-4 minutes.  If you are getting the Title of the article you should also be able to get the URL at the same time.  Then retrieve article by URL.

Comment: @dlatikay I will try this!

Comment: @jdweng You might be right. I'll see if it still fails after I limit the amount of queries that can be run at once.

Comment: @dlatikay Make your comment an answer :)

Comment: Yeah, reading the API docs would probably help :) You can request up to 500 titles in a single query. Also, what's up with those replace commands?

Comment: @Tgr Because some of the titles have "&" or "+" and apparently that messes up the query. I was as surprised as you sound. So the way to solve it was to replace them with words. I don't know why because when you look in the query itself it says like "Sam and Max hit the Road" to "Sam & Max Hit the Road". It's bizzare.

Comment: So you just replaced those characters with random words and expected that to work? I'm not sure you have the right mental model of how computers operate...

Comment: @Tgr Random words..? Not at all. I replaced them with words that works with the Wikipedia Query String. Don't be so condescending.

Comment: Your problem is that you do not percent-encode titles, but that's a common beginner mistake (although avoidable by reading the documentation or sample code). The way you tried to work around it is... creative. It won't work in most cases, and misfire in unexpected ways in some (e.g. [B+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B) and [B Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_Plus) are different things).

Comment: @Tgr My very first solution was to percent-encode my titles. Didn't work. So I switched to what I have now. You are making some pretty arrogant assumptions here.

Comment: You might have made a mistake with the encoding. Or maybe a mistake somewhere else. Since you do not show that code and you do not show the error, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: In any case please do not fire off thousands of requests in parallel. It will cause problems for other users of the API, and might eventually get you banned. As I said, you can specify multiple titles in the same request (see the docs on [multivalue parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats#Multivalue_parameters)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiating roughly 22000 http requests in parallel from one process is just too much. If your machine had unlimited resources and internet connection bandwidth, this would come close to a denial-of-service attack.

What you see is either TCP/IP port exhaustion or queue contention. To resolve it, process your array in smaller chunks, for example fetch 10 items, process those in parallel, then fetch the next ten, and so on.

Specifically [Wikimedia sites have a recommendation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette#Request_limit) to process requests serially:

> There is no hard and fast limit on read requests, but we ask that you be considerate and try not to take a site down. Most sysadmins reserve the right to unceremoniously block you if you do endanger the stability of their site.
>
> If you make your requests in series rather than in parallel (i.e. wait for the one request to finish before sending a new request, such that you're never making more than one request at the same time), then you should definitely be fine.

Be sure to check their API terms of service to learn whether and how many parallel requests would be in compliance.

Comment: Yeah I tried to read through them and see what I could do, but you are right. It's close to a DDOS attack lol. I changed it so that much fewer requests run in parallel now. But I should really just change it to get multiple IDs at a time like you say.

Comment: @Tgr pointed out in the comments that some parameters are multi-value parameters. `titles` [is such a parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Title_normalization). so it will even be possible to combine a query for multiple titles in one request.